# RowFilter only works with column name in C#

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

my RowFilter in windows form application works just fine with column name which NOT is an integer. But the other fields with integer nothing happens. This is my code:

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("group_id LIKE '%{0}%' ", textBox1.Text);
```

If it has to do with the format, have no idea.

Comment: There is no `DataGridView`-`RowFilter`, i guess you mean `DataView.RowFilter`

Comment: Yeah I mean `DataView` . thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `RowFilter` anymore, since .NET 3.5 you can use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
var filteredRows = DV.Table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("group_id").ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text));
```

If you need a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable filteredTable = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

If you need the `DataView` and overwrite the old:

```
DV = filteredTable.DefaultView;
```

I assume that you don't even need the `DataView` anymore.